# Call HTML file as pop up window

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new in MVC & .NET and just out of curiosity, is it possible to call a HTML file as a pop up view ? If yes how would I do it ?

Currently I have a code for pop up window inside my `Index.cshtml`. I want to move the part of the code that is part of the pop up window into separate file or HTML and call it based on conditions by using javascript.

Here's my code for the pop up window:

```
 <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="loginModal" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                ×
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Add To Homepage Prompt</h4>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary button button4">Okay</button>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
@section scripts{

<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#loginModal").modal('show');

</script>  

}
```

Comment: You're code appears to be calling twitter bootstrap.  Are you using bootstrap (and if so what version?)

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap version 3.0

Comment: I have used both bootstrap modal and just iframe approach (using something like fancyapp library) in my projects. For bootstrap modals, you can just put your html into partial views.